# wpf datagrid row selection control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a datagrid(wpftoolkit) in my wpf application and I want to implement the row selection feature by clicking on the datagrids row header. When the user clicks on row header, the whole row must be highlighted, but when he clicks on a cell, only that cell should be highlighted. And, the row deletion option should be enabled only when entire row is highlighted, when a user clicks on a cell, he should not be allowed to delete that row. I tried adding the row header but it is not visible, can someone help with a small code snippet as  I am a newbee in C# WPF domain. So how can I proceed to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set your selection mode to cell, then you can handle your `RowDatagrid` click event an set your Row selected from code behind.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DataGridRowHeader_Click" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            ....
 </DataGrid>

private void DataGridRowHeader_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            // This is when header is double clicked.
}
```

Comment: If I set the selection unit to cell, then the bindings for SelectedItem and CurrentItem wont work, hence I wont be able to delete any row. :(

Comment: You need to handle selecteCell an then get your selected row or selected item. I'm sure that you can get the parent row from cell